# HLookup with a nested MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup, worksheet-function

I'm trying to return the text in the cell below my target. D13 contains text.

```
=HLOOKUP(D13,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,MATCH(D13,'Sheet1'!$E:$E,0)+1,FALSE)
```

Gives me a #N/A (Value Not Available) error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you should tag this with Excel...

Comment: Just did it, thanks.

Comment: @pnuts yes! Thanks! I wonder why the +1 goes down and not right. Is it because the range is just one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much to try and explain the question as the suggested answer:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,MATCH(D13,Sheet1!$E:$E,0)+1)
```

which seems to have worked, assume a layout as:

[image: SO33311122 example]

[MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) looks for the content of cell D13 (ie `dthirteen`) in ColumnE. It finds an exact match in E4 and hence returns `4`, the position of 'dthirteen' in the list (E:E). (The list starts in Row1 so the fourth position is, conveniently, Row4.) [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) looks, here in the same column `E`, for what is in the position given by its second parameter. The second parameter is `4`, as above, plus the `1` required, by the specification, as an offset to wherever `dthirteen` is located.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone who sees this wants to return data in a different column and row than the leftmost row, try this. It references A13 instead of D13 in the MATCH formula to illustrate the point:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$E,MATCH(A13,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,0)+1,5)
```

This will return the value in the cell 1 row below and 4 rows to the right (5th row). Notice that I used multiple columns in the INDEX array, $A:$E. You must include the column(s) and row(s) which contain(s) the value you're looking for in your array. Hope this helps someone.